# Typeorm update entity base on other entiry with DataMapper

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship, typeorm, datamapper

I'm new in TypeORM and now I face with this issue.

I have 2 table `user` and `login_method` - have `One-to-One` relation. I need update the user info base on `login_method` info but it seems TypeORM doesn't support inner join with update. I dont know how to approach using `Update QueryBuilder`.

Here is my entity:

`user.entity`

```js
@Entity('user')
export class User extends BaseEntity{
  @Field()
  @Column({ unique: true })
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true, length: 32 })
  activeCode: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isActivated: boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => LoginMethod, (method) => method.user)
  loginMethod: LoginMethod[];
}
```

`login_method.entity`

```js
export class LoginMethod extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  password: string;

  @Column()
  userId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.loginMethod)
  user: User;
```

My raw SQL like this

```sql
update user
inner join login_method on login_method.userId = user.id
set user.isActivated = 0
where login_method.email = "some random string here"
```

Please let me know how to use `Update QueryBuilder` with `DataMapper` or we have the only way like get the user and then edit this user instance and call `save()` method?